# pushState scrambles browser history

Tags: javascript, html, pushstate

In the test scenario I have two pages pageA and pageB.

In the first step a button triggers `window.history.pushState` call and in the address bar address of pageB is shown.

In the second step browser's address bar is used to make request for pageB. Browser renders content of pageB. In the address bar address of pageB is shown.

In the last step browser's back button is used to return back pageA. In the address bar **address of pageA is shown**. However **browser displays content of pageB** where I was expecting to see content of pageA.

I know I am doing something wrong. Even I have no clue how to describe this behaviour. Do you have any suggestions?

Here you can find demo in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HqECT/3/show/

You may see the implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/HqECT/3/

Note: Test is run in Chrome v30.0.1599.101

Comment: If you are testing on a particular browser, it could be good to actually point which browser you're using.

Comment: You mean `window.history.pushState` :-)

Comment: When you traverse the history elements added via `pushState`, the browser doesn't load the page.  You need to do that using the `window.onpopstate` event.

Answer (score 2):

You need to listen for a [popstate event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onpopstate). The event object will have a `state` property containing whatever data you put into the history when you called `pushState`. If you put the right data in it, you can use that to restore the page to the state for the old URL.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin. Since in the second step a http request is made rather than ´pushState´, in the third step, state property is always ´null´.

Comment: @kokeksibir: The `state` property will be `null` unless you've passed in a state object (the 1st parameter) to `pushState`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat nope, even I set state in first step, it does not work. See updated question, I have added demo in jsFiddle.

Comment: @kokeksibir: `pushState` is a little confusing.  When called, it pushes the current URL (and its state: `window.history.state`) onto the history stack.  Then it changes the current URL and state to what you've passed it.  Check the MDN docs, it's all explained there: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries So in summary, the state object you pass is linked to the *current* page, or rather, it's linked to the URL you pass as the 3rd parameter.  Try to go back, and then go forward again.